# What is the shortcut key for detonate traps?

Tags: pc, dungeon-defenders

I want to be able to forcibly detonate my traps, but its annoying having to navigate to it using the menu.  What is the shortcut key for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind your abilities to your hotkeys (the number keys 0-9 by default, though this can be changed).

To bind Detonate Traps to a hotkey, bring up your abilities, click Hero, hover over Detonate Traps and hold down the hotkey you want to bind it to.

Comment: only 1-4?, that stinks.  I wanted to replace 5 since I do upgrades the least in battle.

Comment: looks like its not just 1-4, I just replaced my upgrade traps with detonate and it worked.

Comment: Nope, you can rebind the entire hot-bar. However, there is a bug some might encounter, that stops some of the keys from being rebind-able. They are working on a fix for it though.

Comment: @yx. Well, the tutorial said 1-4, and the configuration screen has key bindings for 4 custom hotkeys. But it looks like you *can* actually rebind all the number keys.

Comment: (Addendum to the above comment: This has been fixed with a patch at some point today, all the hotkeys can now be rebound)